# second ajax request not working on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am attempting to build a weather station with it's own webserver. So far the page's code is like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WS-100 Server</title>
<script>
    function UpdatePage()
    {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(this.readyState == 4) {
                if(this.status == 200) {
                    if(this.responseText != null) {
                        document.getElementById("currentTemp").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        request.open("GET","ajax_update_temp",true);
        request.send(null);
        request= new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(this.readyState == 4) {
                if(this.status == 200) {
                    if(this.responseText != null) {
                        document.getElementById("currentDatetime").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        request.open("GET","ajax_update_time",true);
        request.send(null);
        setTimeout("UpdatePage()", 10000);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="UpdatePage()">
<h1>WS-100 Weather Station</h1>
<div id="currentDatetime">
    <p> </p>
</div>
<div id="currentTemp">
    <p> </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works great on desktop browsers, but on mobile browsers only the datetime shows, and on my old samsung galaxy, none of it shows. I have considered merging the two queries into one, but eventually I want to do at least two requests: one for the current time and temperature and one which downloads and processes a txt file of the historical measurements.

Is this just a limitation of the browsers or should there be a way to fix it?

Comment: Just a test, why don't you call request2 to the second var?
Maybe you're overwriting request.onreadystatechange and depending on the speed of the device you get the expected answer or not.
 Or you are simply destroying request object

Comment: Tried it to no avail

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `$('document').ready(function());` because in mobile webview some features of desktop browsers are restricted for maintaining performance of it. so some times you need to write `$('document').ready(function());` instead of `onload()`

Answer (score 0):

From Prabhu answer and mine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WS-100 Server</title>
<script>
    function UpdatePage()
    {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(this.readyState == 4) {
                if(this.status == 200) {
                    if(this.responseText != null) {
                        document.getElementById("currentTemp").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        request.open("GET","ajax_update_temp",true);
        request.send(null);
        var request2= new XMLHttpRequest();
        request2.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(this.readyState == 4) {
                if(this.status == 200) {
                    if(this.responseText != null) {
                        document.getElementById("currentDatetime").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        request2.open("GET","ajax_update_time",true);
        request2.send(null);
        setTimeout("UpdatePage()", 10000);
    }
    $('document').ready(function() {
        UpdatePage();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>WS-100 Weather Station</h1>
<div id="currentDatetime">
    <p> </p>
</div>
<div id="currentTemp">
    <p> </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, nope, exact same symptoms

Comment: It's strange because ajax_update_time is the second one and yet it works better

Comment: That's why I was supossing the second was destroying the first request, maybe you need to call `setTimeout("UpdatePage()", 10000);` when the second request ends, just before the closing bracket of `if(this.readyState == 4) {` (be careful with that because if you don't reach readyState 4 you wouldn't  call updatepage function )

Comment: Ok, step by step :) Are you using jquery? (I you don't forgot about `$('document').ready(function() {
        UpdatePage();
    });`

Comment: No I'm not using jquery, although I added <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> just to make your code work.

Comment: That was only for launching UpdatePage once all elements where loaded into DOM but the ten seconds wait in setTimeout("UpdatePage()", 10000); are enough. You can be back to your code (But I encourage you to maintain request2 var name. Second step, you URI are ok because it's  working on desktop. You could split into two functions (getTemp and getDatetime) and call getDatetime from inside getTemp when you have set `document.getElementById("currentTemp").innerHTML`  value. This will ensure you that request won't conflict (but isn't a real solution)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, looks like this will be a tough one